# Render SKScene to SKTexture?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sktexture, skeffectnode

Is there a way in Sprite Kit that I can capture the screen (all the current `SKScene` rendered nodes) to an `SKTexture` so that I can apply a CIFilter and then assign the SKTexture back to a new `SKSpriteNode`?

I know that I can set an `SKEffectNode`, as the parent of my node tree, apply a filter etc and get the result that way but I really need to have a *filtered* `SKTexture` (or `SKSpriteNode`) that I can reuse later?

## EDIT:

Possible solution:

```
textureFromNode:
Renders and returns a Sprite Kit texture that contains the node’s contents.
```

Yup that works:

```
   SKTexture *texture = [[self view] textureFromNode:[self scene]];
   [blurSprite setTexture:texture];
```

Comment: Please write down your solution in a separate answer and mark it as the accepted answer. That way it is easier for other people to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Apple docs:

> textureFromNode: Renders and returns a Sprite Kit texture that
>   contains the node’s contents.

Code example:

```
   SKTexture *texture = [[self view] textureFromNode:[self scene]];
   [blurSprite setTexture:texture];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try with `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` method from `UIView`.

Your `SKScene` is inside an `SKView` that has this method.

After that you can extract the image from the view, and create a `SKNode` with it.